# BCD math library for arbitrary big numbers?

Tags: delphi, biginteger, bigdecimal, bcd

I'm looking for a replacement of the stock Delphi Data.FmtBcd library because I just hit its limits like maximum decimal digits it can represent and program terminates with *EBcdOverflowException*. For the curious, I'm calculating arithmetic series members and need to handle very large numbers - hundred-thousands positions are not so uncommon. And also get results in a reasonable time. I did rewritten part of the code to Python 3.2 for the testing purposes and calculation speed would be sufficient for the Delphi's equivalent.

Some recommendations for a such library, preferably free or opensource ?

Comment: I would be seriously tempted to just use PythonForDelphi, and keep your calculation bits to run as python scripts.

Comment: If you are not concerned with just using BCD and can settle with arbitrary integer/float precision, see [Fast BigFloat unit for Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7371696/576719). See also [General Question About Arbitrary-Precision Math in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6963736/576719).

Comment: @Warren P> Did you mean Python4Delphi ? Regardless whole code is written in Delphi Pascal and I'd wish to avoid mixing with or even rewrite it in another language I'm not so experienced.

Comment: @LU RD> Just tested gmp-wrapper-for-delphi but I'm bit disappointed. Calculating fibonacci sequence is approx. two times slower then in Python. It has to be responsibilty of un-optimized enclosed mpir.dll compiled from C sources.

Comment: Did you try with the latest 2.5.1 mpir.dll [mpir.org](http://www.mpir.org/)?

Comment: It's really trivial to use Python4Delphi.  It isn't hard to mix them.

Comment: @LU RD> Yes, I did used 2.5.1 version of MPIR.

Answer (score 1):

This is an open source unit that I have used in the past for math with 'unlimited' sized integers: http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidB46DDCCA26267DE4B4FB0F7E041A8033A3783AD6.aspx

Would that be what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at TurboPower SysTools4, which is available at:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpsystools/

It contains a High-Precision Floating Point Math Unit, using BCD, for Delphi.