# Delphi - inconsistent floating point roundoff when using FormatFloat('0.##',argValue)

Tags: delphi

Trying to round off double values to two decimal places using function `FormatFloat` (Format string `'0.##'`).

Below are the `input` and `output` values

`231.545 -> 231.54 (but expected output is 231.55)` 
`2.315   -> 2.31 (but expected output is 2.32)`

`23.045  -> 23.05 (gives expected output 23.05)` 
`23.145  -> 23.14 (but expected output 23.15)`

`23.245  -> 23.25 (gives expected output 23.25)` 
`23.345  -> 23.34 (but expected output 23.35)`

`23.445  -> 23.45 (gives expected output 23.45)` 
`23.545  -> 23.55 (gives expected output 23.55)` 
`23.645  -> 23.65 (but expected output 23.64)`

`23.745  -> 23.75 (gives expected output 23.75)` 
`23.845  -> 23.84 (but expected output 23.84)` 
`23.945  -> 23.95 (gives expected output 23.95)`

why this strange behaviour happening? am using Delphi 7.

Comment: Binary floating point values can not represent every value exactly. This is what you are seeing.

Comment: is there any other function get the exact expected value? (or) do we need to write the our own?

Comment: Use a decimal data type. There are libraries around or use currency. See [BigDecimals](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/bigdecimals.html)

Comment: @LURD: I don't think my BigDecimals will compile in Delphi 7. I don't think D7 knows records with methods. It would have to be rewritten to use plain functions.

Answer (score 5):

Binary floating point values can not represent every value exactly. This is what you are seeing.

For example, the value `2.315` is represented in double precision by:

```
2.31499 99999 99999 94670 92948 17992 48605 96656 79931 64062 5
```

This will be rounded to `2.31`

---

If you can use a decimal data type, like `currency`, you can get the wanted output (if currency is within limits of your working range):

```
var
  c : Currency;
begin
  c := 2.315;
  WriteLn(FormatFloat('0.##',c)); // Outputs 2.32
end.
```

An alternative is to use a decimals library, like [BigDecimals](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/bigdecimals.html), but that would require a modern Delphi version with support of records with methods.

Comment: FWIW, for Win32, an alternative is my [Decimals](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/decimals.html) type. Limited range (10^28 .. 10^-28), but faster and smaller (128 bit) than BigDecimal and much more precise than floating point.

Comment: @LU RD : FormatFloat function definition looks like accepting Extended data type, if I use Extended instead of double will it solve this problem?..  Currency data type is not within of my working range)                                                                                           `function FormatFloat(const Format: string; Value: Extended): string;`

Comment: @LU RD: How can I get `2.31499 99999 99999 94670 92948 17992 48605 96656 79931 64062 5` for `2.315` using Delphi code?,, `FormatFloat` function calls `FoatToTextFmt` to do the actual formatting..  there we have the `assembly code`, which I can't understand...

Comment: There is an exact float to string calculator [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=2.335). Also, look at [ID: 19421, ExactFloatToStr_JH0 -- Exact Float to String Routines](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item.aspx?id=19421) for John Herbsters's Delphi code.

Comment: I'm afraid that using extended, will have similar problems as double, but at another level. There may be some others alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9690133/576719)