# is there any possible oway to calculate number bigger than the capacity of integer in php?

Tags: php, string, integer

For some reason I need to work with a number of 150+ digits. I need to add the digits of the number. For that reason I tried to convert the number to string but after 10 digit the number shows EXP. That's why I can't fetch the digits correctly. Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [General Question About Arbitrary-Precision Math in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961685/general-question-about-arbitrary-precision-math-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) and [yes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).